# Is there a PHP extension that wraps the POSIX message queue functions?

Tags: php, linux, posix, message-queue, php-extension

I can see that PHP provides [the semaphore functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php) to access the System V message queue in Linux. However there is no APIs in PHP to access the POSIX message queue. I wonder if there is a PHP extension that can provide APIs for POSIX message queue?

I did Google "PHP POSIX message queue" but it seems nothing really help. There is a [PHPIPCMessageQueue project](https://github.com/jmullee/PhpIPCMessageQueue) in Github, which declares it wraps the POSIX messaeq queue APIs, but the source code shows that it is actually for the System V message queue (calling the semaphore functions).

It seems that I will have to develop a PHP extension by myself. I just can't believe this hasn't been done yet. Can anyone give me some advices?

Comment: If you discover something nobody has done yet it's a *great* opportunity.

Comment: Yes but I really need to confirm that first since I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Since PHP provides semaphore functions for System V message queue, I think it is quite straightforward to ask for something for POSIX message queue... Unless people don't need it because of something I don't know yet...

Comment: To a reasonable approximation, nobody uses message queues - neither SysV nor POSIX flavors.

Comment: Then why those semaphore functions exist in PHP? If nobody use them, they should be deprecated already.

Comment: Well I use them, and would be interested in de POSIX Message Queue API as the SysV version does not support select/poll system calls. I use it to fire up local running scripts that need too much time to run as part of a request.